# Can a user approve without edit permission?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, approval-process

When edting permission level at Sharepoint the Design level has the 'approval' option with the 'edit site' enabled. By default when I click at approval option, it automatic checks the edit box, even if I try to create another permission level. Is there any option for just allow approving?

Answer (score 2):

Permission Level **Approve** includes Edit and approve pages, list items, and documents for publishing sites only.

**Contribute permissions**, plus Approve Items

So you can't restrict approvers from editing a list item. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: Can user having "edit" permission on task list item can approve or reject the approval request ??

Answer (score 0):

Not OOB. Approving an item changes values within the item, and so therefore approvers need edit access. It would be possible for a developer to build a SharePoint solution or app that could run with elevated privileges and approve items.